# Dynamic union of table if a certain field exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a dynamic union over tables that have certain fields (in my example field1 and field2). The union already works but over any table. Now I need to include only the ones that have field1 and field2.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max)

SET @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CASE Len(@SQL) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE ' UNION ALL ' END
+ ' SELECT [field1], [field2] FROM dbo.['
+ NAME + ']'
FROM   sys.tables
WHERE  NAME LIKE 'CUST_TABLE%'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

I guess I need to combine this query somehow:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_NAME like 'CUST_TABLE%'
and COLUMN_NAME='field1'
```

Comment: _columns_, not fields...

Comment: and COLUMN_NAME IN ('field1', 'field2')

Comment: Careful, `'[' + NAME + ']'` doesn't make for safe (injection free SQL). Use `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: @Larnu: It is highly unlikely, though, the system table `sys.tables` contains a row with a `name` that could cause havov inside the brackets in some query's from clause. I think we can easily neglect this possibility.

Comment: You say that, @ThorstenKettner, but that doesn't change that I (and probably yourself) have seen at least one example where a user asking a question here has a `]` in their objects name; and nor does the (how ever small) possibility of it happening mean you should use bad practices. Just like a `int` value could never be used to inject into a dynamic statement doesn't mean it *should* be injected. it should still be **properly** parametrised using `sp_executesql`. Ignoring good/correct practices only when you "think" it's ok will only end up with you doing it when it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Query the view `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. Aggregate per table name and make sure both columns exist for the table by counting them in the `HAVING` clause.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max)

SET @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CASE Len(@SQL) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE ' UNION ALL ' END
                   + ' SELECT [field1], [field2] FROM dbo.[' + table_name + ']'
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name LIKE 'CUST_TABLE%'
GROUP BY table_name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'FIELD1' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'FIELD2' THEN 1 END) > 0

EXEC (@SQL)
```